# Connecting my iMessage with my Mac

Tags: macbook-pro

The iMessage on my Mac is connected to a previous iCloud account and I can't find a way to get messages to send from my new iCloud account.

Comment: Did signing out of the old account and signing in with the new one not work?

Comment: @Devin If my answer below is what you are after, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely,**
if you are looking for multiple ways, e.g. you wish to add another account while keeping the first, [this article](https://www.imore.com/how-to-activate-imessage-iphone-ipad) covers everything there is to know about achieving that result.

Change iMessage accounts on iOS devices:

1. Go to `Settings`
2. `Messages`
3. `Send & Receive`
4. Tap on your current account name to change it.

Change iMessage accounts on macOS devices:

1. Open the `Messages` application on the Mac
2. Go to `Preferences...` under `Messages` in the menu bar
3. Click on `Accounts`
4. *Optional:* Select the account you wish to remove, then click the `Sign out` button.
5. Click the `+` (plus) button at the bottom of the window to add a new one

Is that answering your question? If not, let me know, I'd be more than happy to follow up with you on this.

Answer (score 1):

This does it in Sierra (macOS 10.12.):

Go to Messages > Preferences > Accounts.
In the left-hand pane, select the account which contains "iMessage."
In the right-hand pane, select "Settings."
Click the box labeled "Sign out." Confirm that you wish to sign out.

Correct the Apple ID to show the Apple ID account you wish to use.
Fill in that Apple ID's account password.
Click the box labeled "Sign in."